# Using L'Hopital's rule to find the limit of this function

Tags: limits

I need to find the limit of this function using L'Hopitals rule and I am not sure about my calculations
$$ \lim_{x\to (-\infty)}\frac{e^\frac{1}{x^3}-1}{\arctan\frac{2}{x^4}}$$
Using Lhopital rule and finding the derivative I get
$$ \lim_{x\to (-\infty)}\frac{e^\frac{1}{x^3}*\frac{-3}{x^4} }{\frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{x^8}}* \frac{-8}{x^5}}$$
but Im not sure how to proceed further I tried simplifying but Im not 100% confident that's correct
$$ \lim_{x\to (-\infty)}\frac{e^\frac{1}{x^3}*\frac{-3}{x^4} }{\frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{x^8}}* \frac{-8}{x^5}} = \frac{e^\frac{1}{x^3}*\frac{-3}{1} }{\frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{x^8}}* \frac{-8}{x}} = \frac{e^\frac{1}{x^3}*-3 }{\frac{-8}{(1+\frac{4}{x^8})x}} = \frac{e^\frac{1}{x^3}*-3 }{\frac{-8}{x+\frac{4}{x^7}}} = e^\frac{1}{x^3}*-3  *{\frac{x+\frac{4}{x^7}}{-8}} = 1*-3 {\frac{-\infty+0}{-8}} = -\infty$$

Comment: I may have missed something, but it does seem to be correct. WolframAlpha also gives the same result, so, if there’s a mistake, it should be a minor one.

Comment: @Gauss thanks:), im not sure what WolframAlpha is but il check it out

Comment: No problem! It is a math website that has plenty of calculators and softwares to help solve many different kinds of problems. It is not my favorite, but it does come in handy from time to time ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint:

We don't actually need L'Hopital's rule

Set $-\dfrac1x=h\implies h\to0^+$

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{e^{-h^3}-1}{\arctan(2h^4)}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{e^{-h^3}-1}{-h^3}\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\arctan(2h^4)}{2h^4}}\cdot\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{-h^3}{2h^4}=?$$

Comment: I have to use LHopital's rule unfortunately its part of the problem  but anything additional is helpful thanks